# HTML5 Video Loading, but Not Playing

Tags: html5-video, colorbox

I am attempting to load an HTML5 document via colorbox that plays an video that is added via the video tag. The link to the video is:

```
<a href="content/video/test-video-01.html" class="cboxElement"></a>
```

The JS to add the colorbox is:

```
var $gallery = $( 'a.cboxElement' ).colorbox({
    transition : 'elastic',
    speed : box_speed,
    maxHeight : 700,
    maxWidth : 900,
    initialHeight : 486,
    initialWidth : 722,
    fixed : true,
    preloading : false,
    onCleanup : function() {
        $( 'canvas#connector' ).fadeOut( box_speed );
    },
    onClosed : function() {
        box_opened = false;
        initiateActivity();
    }
} );


$( 'a.cboxElement' ).click( function( e ) {
    $gallery.eq(0).click();
    return false;
} );
```

And finally, test-video-01.html looks like:

```
<video width="722px" height="487px" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://localhost:8888/ipm/content/video/test-video-01.m4v" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="http://localhost:8888/ipm/content/video/test-video-01.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I have added the AddType declarations to my .htaccess file to allow the different MIME types.

The problem is this, when I load the content via Colorbox, it shows the movie and the controls; however, the movie will not play. I can click on the movie timeline and see different frames of the movie, but at no point will it play. When I visit the test-video-o1.html file directly it works perfectly. Colorbox makes an AJAX request to get the HTML file and I'm wondering if this does something to cause the problem. Any help with this would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry posted as an answer as this was too big for a comment.
Is there any chance you can post a jsfiddle?

A few things off the top of my head:

1. What happens when you use the [autoplay](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_video_autoplay.asp) attribute?
2. Have you encoded the video so that the mp4 version has 'faststart'/
   moov atom / optimised for streaming enabled?
3. Do you have Partial Content headers running on the server (206
   response.. often causes probs)
4. Try to attach a js listener to the element for 'canplaythrough'
   event see if it logs.